# How to fire an onserverclick server event for a hyperlink a href in a webusercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, webusercontrol

I have an html hyperlink inside an ASP.NET webusercontrol, i added the runat server attribute to the html hyperlink and fire the onserverclick event to handle it from the code behind C# file but when the event fire the href tag changes to "javascript: __doPostBack('controlname$linkId','')
And the event doesn't fire.

```html
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="uc_users.ascx.cs" Inherits="ExtRa.uc_users" %>
<div class="panel panel-inverse" style="padding-top: 3%; padding-left: 3%;">
    <!-- begin panel-heading -->
    <div class="uk-grid">
        <div class="uk-width-1-1">
            <div class="md-card">
                <div class="md-card-toolbar">
                    <div class="md-card-toolbar-actions">
                        <i class="md-icon material-icons md-card-fullscreen-activate">&#xE5D0;</i>
                        <i class="md-icon material-icons">&#xE5D5;</i>
                        <div class="md-card-dropdown" data-uk-dropdown="{pos:'bottom-left'}">
                            <i class="md-icon material-icons">&#xE5D4;</i>
                            <div class="uk-dropdown uk-dropdown-small">
                                <ul class="uk-nav">
                                    <li><a href="#">Action 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Action 2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h3>المستخدمين
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="md-card-content">
                    <div class="md-card uk-margin-medium-bottom">
                        <div class="md-card-content">
                            <div class="uk-overflow-container">
                                <table id="users_table" <%--class="display"--%> class="uk-table uk-table-nowrap table_check">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="uk-width-1-10 uk-text-center">الاكشن</th>
                                            <th class="uk-width-1-10 uk-text-center">الصورة</th>
                                            <th class="uk-width-1-10 uk-text-center">الاسم</th>
                                            <th class="uk-width-1-10 uk-text-center">اسم المستخدم</th>
                                            <th class="uk-width-1-10 uk-text-center">الشركة</th>
                                            <th class="uk-width-1-10 uk-text-center">تاريخ الانشاء</th>
                                            <th class="uk-width-1-10 uk-text-center">المبلغ المسموح التعامل به</th>
                                            <th class="uk-width-1-10 uk-text-center">فعال ؟</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                        <% 
                                            System.Data.DataTable dt = getUsers();
                                            int rowsCount = dt.Rows.Count;
                                            int totalPages = rowsCount / 5;
                                            foreach (System.Data.DataRow cr in dt.Rows)
                                            {
                                                string u_id = cr["USER_ID"].ToString();
                                                string u_image = cr["IMAGE"].ToString();
                                                string u_name = cr["USER_NAME"].ToString();
                                                string u_login_name = cr["LOGIN_NAME"].ToString();
                                                string u_company = cr["COMPANY_ID"].ToString();
                                                string u_c_date = cr["CREATE_DATE"].ToString();
                                                string u_max_amount = cr["MAX_AMOUNT"].ToString();
                                                string c_is_active = cr["IS_ACTIVE"].ToString();
                                                string u_is_logged = cr["IS_LOG_IN"].ToString();

                                        %>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="uk-text-center">
                                                <a href="#" id="btn_edit" runat="server" onserverclick="btn_edit_ServerClick"><input type="hidden" id="h_edit" value='<%= u_id %>' runat="server" /><i class="md-icon material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                                                <a href="#"><i class="md-icon material-icons">delete</i></a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="uk-text-center"><img class="md-user-image" src='<%="assets/img/user/" + u_image %>' alt=""/></td>
                                            <td class="uk-text-center"><%= u_name %></td>
                                            <td class="uk-text-center"><%= u_login_name %></td>
                                            <td class="uk-text-center"><%= u_company %></td>
                                            <td class="uk-text-center"><%= u_c_date %></td>
                                            <td class="uk-text-center"><%= u_max_amount + " $" %></td>
                                            <td class="uk-text-center">
                                                <%
                                                    string active_class = "", activ_txt = "";
                                                    if (c_is_active == "1")
                                                    {
                                                        active_class = "uk-badge uk-badge-success";
                                                        activ_txt = "فعال";
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        active_class = "uk-badge uk-badge-danger";
                                                        activ_txt = "غير فعال";
                                                    }
                                                %>
                                                <span class='<%=active_class%>'><%=activ_txt %></span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <%
                                                    string login_class = "", login_txt = "";
                                                    if (u_is_logged == "1")
                                                    {
                                                        login_class = "uk-badge uk-badge-defualt";
                                                        login_txt = "مسجل دخول";
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        login_class = "uk-badge uk-badge-warning";
                                                        login_txt = "غير مسجل الدخول";
                                                    }
                                                %>
                                                <span class='<%=login_class%>'><%=login_txt %></span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <ul id="com_pages" class="uk-pagination uk-margin-medium-top">
                                <li class="uk-disabled"><span><i class="uk-icon-angle-double-left"></i></span></li>
                                <li class="uk-active"><span>1</span></li>
                                <li><a href="#" onclick="">2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                                <li><span>&hellip;</span></li>
                                <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="uk-icon-angle-double-right"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end panel-heading -->
</div>
```

The code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ExtRa.Data;

namespace ExtRa
{
    public partial class uc_users : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public DataTable getUsers(){ return da.users_get(); }
        protected void btn_delete_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e){}
        protected void btn_edit_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["action"] = "edit";
            Session["u_a_id"] = h_edit.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

So, how i can get the event fired from the server side ?

Comment: you should use onserverclick inside the userControlclass as well or show some code,I will help more either use findcontrol method for search to control id inside the inspect elements of webbrowser over your link id

Comment: its working for me

Comment: i use the following hyperlink <a href="#" id="btn_edit" runat="server" onserverclick="btn_edit_ServerClick">  inside uc_users.ascx  ======> and at runtime the hyperlink become: <a id="uc_users_btn_edit" href="javascript:__doPostBack('uc_users$btn_edit','')"><input name="uc_users$h_edit" type="hidden" id="uc_users_h_edit" value="<%= u_id %>"><i class="md-icon material-icons"></i></a>

Comment: I used your href inside usercontrol.It quite working and redirected page to google link on server side..

Comment: Edit your question with class and design code to make it more clear for all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with "CausesValidation"

Set CausesValidation="false" on the control and it will remove the: `javascript: __doPostBack('` from the outputted control

Somewhere on this page or somewhere included in your output of this you may have a RequiredFieldValidator.  Once you add one to the page you start getting this _doPostBack stuff because VS thinks it should be validated first.